# Angular - How to Iterate through an object that some of the keys are undefined

Tags: html, angular, for-loop, object, iteration

So I have **objectA** and **objectB**

```
objectA {
    0: {name: 'M', date: '2021-10-24'}
    1: {name: 'T', date: '2021-10-25'}
    2: {name: 'W', date: '2021-10-26'}
    3: {name: 'T', date: '2021-10-27'}
    4: {name: 'F', date: '2021-10-28'}
    5: {name: 'S', date: '2021-10-29'}
    6: {name: 'S', date: '2021-10-30'}
}
```

```
objectB {
    2021-10-29: [{…}]
    2021-10-30: [{…}, {…}]
}
```

**objectA** holds all the days in the current week and **objectB** holds all the appointments(building an appointments app) in the current week, so **objectB** can have an appointment every day, having the dates of the appointments as keys or it can have only one, two or even 0 date keys, depending if there are appointments or not. In the above example there is only one appointment on the 29'th and two on the 30'th.

My problem is that I want to iterate through **objectB** in the HTML(to get some appointment data) by getting the keys(the date strings) from **objectA**. I get this Error and the iteration stops because the key I'm trying to access does not exist.

ERROR:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '2021-10-24')
```

This is my HTML:

```
 <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td *ngFor="let day of objectA">
             <div *ngFor="let app in objectB[day.date]">
                 <span *ngIf="app">{{ app.startTime | date : 'HH:mm' }}</span>
             </div>         
         </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

So I guess my question is how do I iterate through **objectB** without knowing all its keys, or how to  make the for loop ignore the undefined and just continue to iterate.

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with this exactly? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu this is the error I get "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '2021-10-24')", I also edited the post

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

You need [`KeyValuePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) to iterate for the object in order to get keys and values.

```
<td *ngFor="let kv of objectA | keyvalue;">
  <div *ngFor="let app of objectB[kv.value.date]">
    <span *ngIf="app">{{ app.startTime | date: 'HH:mm' }}</span>
  </div>
</td>
```

[Sample Solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tkw97t?file=src/app/app.component.html)

---

### Solution 2

Convert `objectA` to array with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```js
aList = Object.keys(this.objectA).map((x: any) => this.objectA[x]);
```

```
<td *ngFor="let day of aList;">
  <div *ngFor="let app of objectB[day.date]">
    <span *ngIf="app">{{ app.startTime | date: 'HH:mm' }}</span>
  </div>
</td>
```

[Sample Solution 2 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-csi2w2)

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
     <td *ngFor="let day of objectA">
<ng-container *ngIf="objectB[day.date]">
         <div *ngFor="let app in objectB[day.date]">
             <span *ngIf="app">{{ app.startTime | date : 'HH:mm' }}</span>
         </div>   
</ng-container>

  
   </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Just add an if condition and check if that key exist in ObjectB then loop thought it